# My code not working from case 5 up to 9

Tags: javascript, if-statement, switch-statement, control-flow

My code is working fine from case 2 upto case 4. But from case 5 up to case 9,it just produces the output of inside switch statements and do not check for if else conditions below for case 5 upto case 9. I think there is some minor error, I am not able to identify. Please help me see where is the problem.

Here is the code:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
  var a = [],
    array,input,output,userclicked,comp,ranOne=0,ranTwo=0,ranThree=0,ranFour=0,ranFive=0,ranSix=0,ranSeven=0,ranEight=0,ranNine=0;
  array = [".1,.2,.3,.4,.5,.6,.7,.8,.9"];

 bootbox.dialog({
  message:"Choose X or O",
  title:"Tic Tac Toe game",
  buttons:{
    success:{
      label:"X",
      className: "btn-success",
      callback:function(){
        input="X";
        output="O";
/*var randomInitialOutput = (function(ranarrayElement) {
var ranarray=[".1",".5",".7",".3",".9"];
  ranarrayElement = ranarray[Math.floor(Math.random() * 5)]; //random element
  return ranarrayElement;
})();*/
var randomInitialOutput=".1";
  $(randomInitialOutput).html(output);  //random initial output
        a.push(output);
     $(array.join("")).click(function() {
    $(this).html(input);
       var hello=this;//Crazy code starts
    hello=   hello.className.split(/\s+/)
       var blaharray=["1","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9"]
       for(var i=0;i<hello.length;i++){
 if(blaharray.indexOf(hello[i])>0){
  userclicked="."+hello[i];
}
}//Crazy code ends to tell us what the user clicked
 if(randomInitialOutput==".1"){
   $(".1").off("click");
if((ranTwo==0)&&(ranThree==0)&&(ranFour==0)&&(ranFive==0)&&(ranSix==0)&&(ranSeven==0)&&(ranEight==0)&&(ranNine==0)){
   switch (userclicked) {
     case ".2":
     ranTwo++;
       $(".7").html(output);
        break;
        case ".3":
          ranThree++;
           $(".7").html(output);
          break;
          case ".4":
            ranFour++;
            $(".5").html(output);
            break;
            case ".5":
              ranFive++;
              $(".9").html(output);
              break;
              case ".6":
              ranSix++;
                $(".3").html(output);
                break;
                case ".7":
                  ranSeven++;
                  $(".3").html(output);
                  break;
                  case ".8":
                    ranEight++;
                    $(".3").html(output);
                    break;
                    case ".9":
                      ranNine++;
                      $(".3").html(output);
                      break;
   }
 }//if

 if((ranTwo==1)&&(userclicked==".4")){
   $(".5").html(output);
   ranTwo=2;
 }else if ((ranTwo==2)&&(userclicked==".3")) {
  $(".9").html(output); //comp won
}else if ((ranTwo==2)&&(userclicked==".9")) {
    $(".3").html(output); //comp  won
}
if ((ranThree==1)&&(userclicked==".4")) {
  $(".9").html(output);
  ranThree=2;
}else if ((ranThree==2)&&(userclicked==".5")) {
$(".8").html(output); //comp won
}else if ((ranThree==2)&&(userclicked==".8")) {
  $(".5").html(output); //comp won
}

if ((ranFour==1)&&(userclicked==".9")) {
$(".3").html(output);
ranfour=2;
}else if ((ranfour==2)&&(userclicked==".2")) {
$(".7").html(output);//comp won
}else if ((ranfour==2)&&(userclicked==".7")) {
$(".2").html(output);//comp won
}

if((ranFive==1)&&(userclicked==".7")){//error starts from number 5 upto 9
$(".3").html(output);
ranfive=2;
}else if ((ranfive==2)&&(userclicked==".2")) {
$(".6").html(output);//comp won
}else if ((ranfive==2)&&(userclicked==".6")) {
$(".2").html(output);//comp won
}

if((ranSix==1)&&(userclicked==".2")){
$(".7").html(output);
ranSix=2;
}else if ((ranSix==2)&&(userclicked==".4")) {
$(".5").html(output);//comp won
}else if ((ranSix==2)&&(userclicked==".5")) {
$(".4").html(output);//comp won
}

if ((ranSeven==1)&&(userclicked==".2")) {
$(".5").html(output);
ranSeven=2;
}else if ((ranSeven==2)&&(userclicked==".9")) {
$(".8").html(output);
ranSeven=3;
}else if ((ranSeven==3)&&(userclicked==".6")) {
$(".4").html(output);//tie
}else if ((ranSeven==3)&&(userclicked==".4")) {
$(".6").html(output); //tie
}

if((ranEight==1)&&(userclicked==".2")){
$(".5").html(output);
ranEight=2;
}else if ((ranEight==2)&&(userclicked==".9")) {
$(".7").html(output);//comp won
}else if ((ranEight==2)&&(userclicked==".7")) {
$(".9").html(output);//comp won
}


if ((ranNine==1)&&(userclicked==".2")) {
$(".7").html(output);
ranNine=2;
}else if ((ranNine==2)&&(userclicked==".4")) {
$(".5").html(output);//comp won
}else if ((ranNine==2)&&(userclicked==".5")) {
$(".4").html(output);//comp won
}


}// randomInitialOutput==".1"
else if (randomInitialOutput==".5") {

}else if (randomInitialOutput==".7") {

}else if (randomInitialOutput==".3") {

}else if (randomInitialOutput==".9") {

}
    a.push($(this).html());
        if (a.length == 9) {
    $(".yo").html("Game Over!");
   } //Game Over
  });
 }//callback
},
   main:{
      label:"O",
      className: "btn-primary",
      callback:function(){
       input="O";
 $(array).click(function() {
  $(this).html(input);
  a.push($(this).html());
  if (a.length == 9) {
    $(".yo").html("Game Over!");
  } //Game Over
});
      }//callback
    }//main
  }//buttons
  });//BootBoxDialogue
});//document ready function
```

Here the link to my code http://codepen.io/meow414/pen/rLJaPJ
Cases ".1",".2" etc are used to denote class of a box div

Comment: I don't see any difference in the code for these cases inside the `switch` statement.  Maybe you have a problem with your logic?

Comment: My God, 182 lines... please, provide a [_minimal_ example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's what I think. I don't find any difference,but from case 5 upto 9 it is not executing relevant if else  for case 5 to 9. If else loop of case ".5" is where ranFive==1,but after the switch statement this if else is not executed like it is easily for case ".2" to ".4" Where is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

There is spelling mistake, ranFour is written ranfour in loop and ranFive is written ranfive. Now working correctly.